Closed form of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(2 \pi p_{n} x)$
Question: Is there a closed form for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(2 \pi p_{n} x)$ ? Here, $p_{n}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number.
Context:
I know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \cos(2 \pi n x)$ approaches a Dirac Comb. I am also loosely aware that there are some mathematical explanations for distribution of prime numbers not sharing the properties of random numbers. I don't know what to expect when sinusoids of prime frequencies are added together.
What did I try?

I tried plotting for various upper limits of $n$. I am not able to figure out any trend except the obvious observation that at $x \in \mathbb{z}$, the cosines add up to $n$.
I also tried looking at it in Fourier domain. The problem transforms to finding a closed form of $\sum \frac{1}{p_{n}+x}$. I know that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+x} = -\psi(x)$, where $\psi(x)$ is the digamma function. I am not able to use that result to get what I want.


Not, the Dirac comb is not a function, it is a distribution. This likewise doesn't converge to a function, although it might converge to a distribution.

Since $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}p_n=\infty$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\cos(2\pi p_n x)$ does not exist and the sum diverges. Right?

Yes, agreed to both of your comments. Distribution type closed form is fine.

@TymaGaidash The limit given which is the Dirac Comb is a l8mit as a distribution, so it doesn't need to converge as a limit of functions.

I see no reason to expect a known closed formula. The closed formula in the other case results from the closed formula for $\sum_n z^n,$ while there is no known closed formula for $\sum_n z^{p_n}.$

@TymaGaidash . The reason I introduced the Fourier domain in my question is: some distributions have a nice function representation in Fourier domain, but not others. For example, FT of dirac comb is another dirac comb, but FR of dirac pulse is a constant (function). Any domain is fine, as long as it leads to studying it more concisely than as an infinite sum, for my purposes
